# Missing 'cond' parameter to $filter

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, robo3t

I want to query my `movieStyle` that is an array.

I think I have used the key words that are `aggregate`  `$map`  `$filter`  `input`  `as`  `cond`

I use the query comman in Robo3T:

```
db.getCollection('Tainan').aggregate([
            {                
              "$project": { 
                  theater: true,
                  theaterCn: true,
                  movie: {
                    $filter: {
                      input: {
                        $map: {
                          input: "$movie",
                          as: "movie",
                          in: {
                              cnName: "$$movie.cnName",
                              enName: "$$movie.enName",
                              versionType: "$$movie.versionType",
                              movieStyle: {
                                $filter: {
                                  input: "$$movie.movieStyle",
                                  as: "movieStyle",
                                  cond: { $eq: [ "$$movieStyle", '動作' ] }  
                                }
                              }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                    }
                  }
              }
            }
        ])
```

But I get the error:

```
Error:
Assert: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Missing 'cond' parameter to $filter",
    "code" : 28650,
    "codeName" : "Location28650"
} : aggregate failed
```

Why ?  Do I filter my `movie.movieStyle` gets something wrong ?

Here is my data structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc6af1ce9427ea77e75eacc"),
    "theater" : "TodayTainan",
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            120.196866, 
            22.99322
        ]
    },
    "movie" : [ 
        {
            "movieStills" : [ 
                "https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/x/r/w340/i/o/production/movie-photos/January2018/VOTtTo0hq2Sc0ncv8xYE-1000x667.jpg"
            ],
            "videoId" : [ 
                "rUAri_35CIA", 
                "gV6cD1iUp_0"
            ],
            "imdbScore" : "7.3",
            "cnName" : "蟻人與黃蜂女",
            "versionType" : "數位",
            "movieStyle" : [ 
                "\n                    動作\n                  ", 
                "\n                    科幻\n                  "
            ],
            "rottenScore" : "88%",
            "releasedTime" : [ 
                ISODate("2018-10-17T13:10:00.000Z"), 
                ISODate("2018-10-17T17:30:00.000Z"), 
                ISODate("2018-10-17T21:40:00.000Z")
            ],
            "movieTime" : "片　　長：01時59分",
            "movieActorPhoto" : [ 
                "https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/x/r/h290/i/o/production/names/May2018/P7wuxMUcAILicv9huTkf-2790x2790.jpg"
            ],
            "movieActorCn" : [ 
                "保羅路德", 
                "伊凡潔琳莉莉"
            ],
            "movieDate" : "date：2018-07-04",
            "enName" : "Ant-Man and the Wasp",
            "movieContent" : "some content",
            "photoHref" : "https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/x/r/w420/i/o/production/movies/May2018/nJipiMxyde97aeNbkGkJ-1045x1500.jpg"
        }, 
        {
            "movieStills" : [ 
                "https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/x/r/w340/i/o/production/movie-photos/May2018/Hnk8uVTwSAN50pDZt6gc-2160x900.jpeg"
            ],
            "videoId" : [ 
                "utddeo-pulY", 
                "krd8J_clTyo"
            ],
            "imdbScore" : "5.9",
            "cnName" : "摩天大樓",
            "versionType" : "數位",
            "movieStyle" : [ 
                "\n                    動作\n                  ", 
                "\n                    懸疑/驚悚\n                  "
            ],
            "rottenScore" : "46%",
            "releasedTime" : [ 
                ISODate("2018-10-17T11:10:00.000Z"), 
                ISODate("2018-10-17T15:20:00.000Z"), 
                ISODate("2018-10-17T19:40:00.000Z")
            ],
            "movieTime" : "片　　長：01時43分",
            "movieActorPhoto" : [ 
                "https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/x/r/h290/i/o/production/names/June2017/o1hsVz7VPYYYEs0YuYvX-2131x3500.jpg"
            ],
            "movieActorCn" : [ 
                "巨石強森", 
                "帕布羅薛伯"
            ],
            "movieDate" : "date：2018-07-12",
            "enName" : "Skyscraper",
            "movieContent" : "some content",
            "photoHref" : "https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/x/r/w420/i/o/production/movies/May2018/sy8K5jWAfeiqv9wH25uI-947x1500.JPG"
        }
    ],
    "phone" : "06-2205151",
    "address" : "some address",
    "theaterCn" : "Today theater"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

And Here is my code about `$filter releasedTime` , it works. I just can't figure it out why I can't `$filter movieStyle`

```
db.getCollection('Tainan').aggregate([
            {                
              "$project": { 
                  theater: true,
                  theaterCn: true,
                  movie: {
                    $filter: {
                      input: {
                        $map: {
                          input: "$movie",
                          as: "movie",
                          in: {
                              cnName: "$$movie.cnName",
                              enName: "$$movie.enName",
                              versionType: "$$movie.versionType",
                              releasedTime: {
                                $filter: {
                                  input: "$$movie.releasedTime",
                                  as: "movie",
                                  cond: { $and: [
                                    {$gte: [ "$$movie", 2018-10-17 10:20:00.000Z`) ]},
                                    {$lte: [ "$$movie", 2018-10-17 22:20:00.000Z`) ]} 
                                  ]}
                                }
                              }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      as: "movie",
                      cond: "$$movie"
                    }
                  }
              }
            }
        ])
```

Comment: Why do you applied first `$filter` before `$map` ? Remove it because it doesn't contain `cond` part.

Comment: If I remove the first `$filter` the error will be gone, but the result movieStyle will be empty.

Comment: Do you want to filter `"$movie"`? if yes how ?

Comment: Which version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: I update a working query about `$filter`my `releasedTime` in my question, I can't figure it out why it is not working when I change it to be `movieStyle`.  My mongo version is `MongoDB shell version v4.0.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

Your `movieStyle` array contains `/n` in it elements. You can remove them using [**`$trim`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trim/) aggregation.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "theater": true,
    "theaterCn": true,
    "movie": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$movie",
            "as": "movie",
            "in": {
              "cnName": "$$movie.cnName",
              "enName": "$$movie.enName",
              "versionType": "$$movie.versionType",
              "movieStyle": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$$movie.movieStyle",
                  "as": "movieStyle",
                  "cond": {
                    "$eq": [
                      { "$trim": { "input": "$$movieStyle" }},
                      "動作"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "as": "movie",
        "cond": "$$movie"
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Hmm...its strange, Dose it should return `result 0` or `empty` If the value is not equal `$eq`  ?   Thank you very much Anthony, your code is working.

Comment: yes It returns empty as you were getting empty array before . Isn't it? ;-)

Comment: Ya I mean that I should get something like `0` instead of `Missing 'cond' parameter to $filter` when I use the wrong query command.

Comment: `Missing 'cond' parameter to $filter` you were getting this because you were not applying `cond` part to the `$filter` aggregation. `$filter` aggregation has three parameter `input`, `as` and `cond` and you were missing the last one. See [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/).

Comment: Thanks for your explaination Anthony, one more thing I want to ask about `input` `as` `cond` because I think I have add `$filter: {
                                  input: "$$movie.movieStyle",
                                  as: "movieStyle",
                                  cond: { $eq: [ "$$movieStyle", '動作' ] }  
                                }` in the beginning right ?

Comment: Your this `$filter` part was ok. But the `$filter` where `input` was `$map` were missing `cond`

Comment: I see it ! Thanks for your help truly.